# How to make a gridview column an email link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I picked up some code that is building a Gridview with a SQLDataAdapter.

One of the columns is an email address that I would like to make a hyper link to open Outlook (Users defautl email client).

The Gridview is all managed in code behind. Is there some way to do this?

Here is the code....

```
 If counter > 0 Then    
    Dim command4 As New SqlCommand(queryString4, connection) 
    Dim mySQLDataAdapter4 As New SqlDataAdapter(command4) 

    mySQLDataAdapter4.Fill(emailDataset, "needsEmail") 
 End If 
Next  
connection.Close() 


GridView4.DataSource = emailDataset 
GridView4.DataBind()
```

There is code that checks that data is returned that I have removed for readability.

I return 4 columns in the query. Everything works great, just want to make one of the columns and active email link.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this with a template field like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="email">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="mailto:<%# Bind("email") %>"><%# Bind("email") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

should render

```
|<a href="bob@bob.com">bob@bob.com</a>|
```

**Edit**:

You don't need **all** the columns to be template fields. The rest of the columns can simply be like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyName" HeaderText="MyName"
        SortExpression="MyName" />
<!--adding your templatefield-->
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="email">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="mailto:<%# Bind("email") %>"><%# Bind("email") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You didn't post any of your gridview  code so I'm guessing about something of this. If you are trying to get the email out of the gridview in the code behind you can look at [this link](http://codeproject.wordpress.com/2007/10/24/gridview-hidden-fieldhow-to-get-hidden-field-value-in-gridviewdatakeys/). It describes hiding an ID field but you should be able to do the same with the raw email address.

Comment: Works Perfect!!!! got some columns to clean up since its repeated now but no big deal. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I have an issue now as I have converted the columns to TemplateFields, and set autoGenerate columns to False. I can not read the columns with Dim emailAdd As String = row.Cells(2).Text and Dim userName As String = row.Cells(0).Text which I use when I run a routine to send an email to all the users listed in the Gridview. Ant ideas how to do this, other than setting AutoGenRows to False? The columns don't exit in the gridview they are buit by the SQLDataAdapter, see OP.

Comment: take a  look at my edit and see if that helps. let me know if I can assist you further

Comment: Okay, I am reviewing now. I will also update my code with what I have now. I did add the others fields and BoundFields. But I read the email and user name in code behind with the stmts in my last comment, I can not find the email field when it is a Template Field. I'lll update more shortly.

Comment: Now working perfectly, Thanks again!!!!!  Adding the DataKeyNames was the trick. No probelms now!!

Comment: yup, no problem. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set up a templatecolumn in your gridview and bind it to the email address.

[More information](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up a method on the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event for your grid in the code behind. You'll have access to that row's data, and can format each cell as you'd like (in this case a `mailto:email` link).